# Saving Checklist Selection

Tags: java, arraylist, save, jcheckbox

I am having trouble figuring out how to do the following. I am trying to enable the user to check the books he wants using my checklist, but I cannot figure out how to save his selections (the checked books) in order to determine the price he has to pay. Here is my checklist code:

```
for(int k=0;k<catalogue.getCatalogue().size();k++)
    {
        frame.add(new JCheckBox(catalogue.cat.get(k).toString()));
    }


    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(900,900);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){ public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){System.exit(0);}});
```

It just shows the list of books (catalogue is an Arraylist containing the books, which I read from a file) with a checkbox beside it. I need help in figuring out how to "save" his selections so that I can store it in another arraylist of books.

Comment: you should create an array of JCheckBox with that first loop, and add the checkboxs to the frame. this way you have an array of all the checkboxs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an Array/ArrayList of JCheckLists. For example:

```
JCheckBox[] checkboxes = new JCheckBox[catalogue.getCatalogue().size()];
```

And then:

```
for(int k=0;k<catalogue.getCatalogue().size();k++)
{
    checkboxes[k] = new JCheckBox(catalogue.cat.get(k).toString()));
    frame.add(checkboxes[k]);
}
```

Now you can easily check the state of each checkbox, for example, you can reference the first one by checkboxes[0]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Sorry for being a bother, but now I don't know how to actually save the selections...like I know I have to add an additional button as a "save my selections"...will I then be able to check the checkboxes' states after the said button is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

```
JCheckBox[] checkboxArray = new JCheckBox[catalogue.getCatalogue().size()];

for(int k=0;k<catalogue.getCatalogue().size();k++)
    {
        checkboxArray[k] = new JCheckBox(catalogue.cat.get(k).toString());
        frame.add(checkboxArray[k]);
    }
```

//

```
you can also add a ItemListener to your checkboxs



  private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener
        {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getSource() == check1)
                {
                    if(check1.isSelected())
                    {
                                  //do something
                                }   
                }
            }
        }
  JCheckBox[] checkboxArray = new JCheckBox[catalogue.getCatalogue().size()];
  CheckBoxListener listener = new CheckBoxListener();

    for(int k=0;k<catalogue.getCatalogue().size();k++)
        {
            checkboxArray[k] = new JCheckBox(catalogue.cat.get(k).toString());
            checkboxArray[k].addItemListener(listener);
            frame.add(checkboxArray[k]);
        }
```

//now when a box is checked happens the an ItemEvent will triger